# How does jQuery install with Bower?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bower, bower-install

`bower install jquery` works fine. Although I don't see jquery in http://bower.io/search/?q=owner:jquery.

Also https://github.com/jquery/jquery doesn't have a `bower.json` yet I can install, howcome ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely to the last line when you install jQuery using bower you can see that bower used the following repository:
https://github.com/components/jquery

> d:\temp>bower install jquery
>
> bower not-cached    git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
>
> bower resolve       git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
>
> bower download      https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/2.1.4.tar.gz
>
> bower extract       jquery#* archive.tar.gz
>
> bower resolved      git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
>
> bower install       jquery#2.1.4
>
> jquery#2.1.4 **bower_components\jquery**

You can find the packet on the bowerwebsite here:
http://bower.io/search/?q=owner:components%20property-book-client

Comment: This is quite confusing. I thought the last line `bower_components/jquery` denoted the folder/directory in which it was downloaded/created. Also howcome the component is named `property-book-client` in the bower registry whereas on github it is `components/jquery` ?